# How do I rename many windows files to exclude a specific string in the new name?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

For examples, the test file name is  "Android SQLApp v1.rar_[ID-9999_mail@my.com].BYF" to a new name of "Android SQLApp v1.rar"? Notice we have spaces and special characters in the name. How can I simplify in mass filenames like this using powershell or linux?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the code you are trying to make work into the question as text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script like this:

```
$toRemove = "_[ID-9999_mail@my.com].BYF"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*$toRemove"
  | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.FullName.Replace($toRemove, "")  }
```

You set the string to remove, then iterate files and position it within the filename with `-Filter` and `*` wildcard matching. Then you go through all results (`%`) and rename each file with `Rename-Item`. `-NewName`

Alternatively, one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*_[ID-9999_mail@my.com].BYF" | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.FullName.Replace("_[ID-9999_mail@my.com].BYF", "")  }
```